# Send email on A DAILY BASIS from a specific google sheet TAB (GOOGLE APP SCRIPT)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to modify the following App Script in such a way that I can schedule the email to be sent daily:

```
 function sendSheetTab() {
 var sheetName = 'SHEETNAME'
 var destinationEmail = 'yourname@your.com'


 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)


 var params = ss.getId() + "/export?gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + "&format=pdf"
 var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + params


 var options = {
     "method": "GET",
     "headers": {
         "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
     }
 };


 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , options)
 var contents = result.getContent()


 var subject = 'Sending sheet: ' + sheetName
 var body = 'With Apps Script'
 GmailApp.sendEmail(destinationEmail, subject, body, {attachments:[{fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]})
```

Is someone able to help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installable trigger.  Start a new file and paste the code in the new file.  Then save it and run it (and authorize it) and the daily triggers will be set up.

This code should work for you:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
// Trigger function everyday around 6:00 am   
 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendSheetTab')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(6)
      .nearMinute(0)
      .everyDays(1) 
      .create();
}
```

You can view the new trigger by going to the left sidebar and selecting Triggers.
[image: Screenshot]

If you click the Edit icon on the trigger you can see the details of the trigger.
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Thank you Codedabbler. This is amazing. It works wonder!

Comment: Do you happen to know how i can attach an image of the tab to the body so people don't have to open the pdf? thanks :-)

Comment: If this solved your question, please consider clicking the check mark to mark it solved so all can know this answer solved the question.  In regard to attaching an image, it would be better to submit a new question in order to stay focused and keep each question to a single topic.